# read.sas7bdat unable to read compressed file

Tags: r, sas

I am trying to read a .sas7bdat file in R. When I use the command

```
library(sas7bdat)
read.sas7bdat("filename")
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in read.sas7bdat("county2.sas7bdat") : file contains compressed data
```

I do not have experience with SAS, so any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the sas7bdat vignette [`vignette('sas7bdat')`], `COMPRESS=BINARY` (or `COMPRESS=YES`) is not currently supported as of 2013 (and this was the vignette active on 6/16/2014 when I wrote this).  `COMPRESS=CHAR` is supported.

These are basically internal compression routines, intended to make filesizes smaller.  They're not as good as `gz` or similar (not *nearly* as good), but they're supported by SAS transparently while writing SAS programs.  Obviously they change the file format significantly, hence the lack of implementation yet.

If you have SAS, you need to write these to an uncompressed dataset.

```
options compress=no;
libname lib '//drive/path/to/files';
data lib.want;
set lib.have;
run;
```

That's the simplest way (of many), assuming you have a libname defined as `lib` as above and change `have` and `want` to names that are correct (`have` should be the filename without extension of the file, in most cases; `want` can be changed to anything logical with A-Z  or underscore only, and 32 or fewer characters).

If you don't have SAS, you'll have to ask your data provided to make the data available uncompressed, or as a different format. If you're getting this from a PUDS somewhere on the web, you might post where you're getting it from and there might be a way to help you identify an uncompressed source.

Comment: I do not have SAS but good to know.I might have to give it a shot.Thanks very much!

Comment: For future reference, dsread and DsShell (both available at http://www.oview.co.uk) support compressed data sets using either BIN or CHAR compression.

Answer (score 7):

This admittedly is not a pure R solution, but in many situations (e.g. if you aren't on a pc and don't have the ability to write the SAS file yourself) the other solutions posted are not workable.

Fortunately, Python has a module (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sas7bdat) which supports reading compressed SAS data sets - it's certainly better using this than needing to acquire SAS if you don't already have it.  Once you extract the file and save it to text via Python, you can then access it in R.

```
from sas7bdat import SAS7BDAT
import pandas as pd

InFileName = "myfile.sas7bdat"
OutFileName = "myfile.txt"

with SAS7BDAT(InFileName) as f:
    df = f.to_data_frame()

df.to_csv(path_or_buf = OutFileName, sep = "\t", encoding = 'utf-8', index = False)
```

Answer (score 6):

The haven package can read compressed SAS-files:

```
library(haven)
df <- read_sas("sasfile.sas7bdat")
```

But only SAS-files which are compressed using `compress=char`, but not `compress=binary`.

So haven will be able to read this SAS-file:

```
data output.compressed_data_char (compress=char);
set inputdata;
run;
```

But not this SAS-file:

```
data output.compressed_data_binary (compress=binary);
set inputdata;
run;
```

https://cran.r-project.org/package=haven

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001002773.htm

Answer (score 4):

"RevoScaleR" is a good package to read SAS data sets (compressed or uncompressed).You can use `rxImport` function of this package. Below is the example

## Importing library

```
library(RevoScaleR)
```

## Reading data

```
R_df_name <- rxImport("fake_path/file_name.sas7bdat")
```

The speed of this function is far better than haven/sas7bdat/sas7bdat.parso. I hope this helps anyone who struggles to read SAS data sets in R.

Cheers!

Comment: Note that package ‘RevoScaleR’ is not available (for R version 3.4.1)

Comment: RevoScaleR is part of Microsoft R packages.

Answer (score 0):

I found R to be the easiest for this kind of challenge, especially with compressed sas7dbat files, three simple lines:

```
library(haven)
data <- read_sas("yourfile.sas7dbat")
```

and then transform it to csv

```
write.csv(data,"data.csv")
```